# Sign-in with google for android is not working in release apk after minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, proguard

I did my research for whole day. Most of people are facing issue due to release SHA1, but i have checked using all methods (command line and Android studio). I am getting same release hash key and it is working if i make minifyEnabled false in release build.

If i make minifyEnabled true to obfuscate files google sign in is not working.

here is my proguard file

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

# -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
# -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
# -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
# -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
# -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
# -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
# -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
# -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *

-keepclassmembernames class *
{
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil {*;}

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-adaptresourcefilenames

-adaptresourcefilecontents

-keepdirectories

#-keepclassmembers class * {
#  public void *(android.view.View);
#}

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
   public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
   public *;
}

-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*
-dontwarn **$$Lambda$*

# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions

-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}

-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
-keep class com.google.** {*;}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Any help is really appreciated, spent whole day on this issue!!

Comment: Define "Not working". crashes? if so, post crash log

Comment: It is not crashing, i am not able to sign in with google.

Comment: Why -1, i tried all the ways people suggested in other issues, my issue is different. If you know answer pls provide link.

Answer (score 3):

After 2 days of hardwork, i resolved it. Issue is with retrofit and model classes.

We should not allow to rename model classes so kept

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}

-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
 -keep class com.yourproject.YourClass**
 -keepclassmembers class com.yourproject.YourClass** {
    *;
 }
```